# Justify the existence of a set by using $\Delta_1^0$ comprehension

Tags: logic, reverse-math

[Here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/cobb/cobb.pdf), page $9$, in the proof of Theorem $I.5$, there is this sentence

$$X_k=\{ m | (m \geq k+2) \wedge (b_{m,m} - a_{m,m} \leq 2^{-k+2}) \}$$

exists by $\Delta_1^0$ comprehension.

Question: Why the set exists by $\Delta_1^0$ comprehension? How to express the set $X_k$ using quantifier $\forall$ or $\exists$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that is, on one hand, often routine once you understand it, and, on the other hand,  too long to actually write out by hand. To work in Reverse Mathematics, you need to develop a feel for which formulas will be expressible in a $\Delta^0_1$ manner.

The rule of thumb is to rely on Church's thesis: if the definition would be computably decidable in the standard model, it is likely going to fit into the $\Delta^0_1$ comprehension scheme.  The formal verification of this for a particular definition requires expanding out the definition into smaller pieces until it is obvious that each piece can be expressed in the appropriate way.

Working formally, the first stage of this expansion gives these two formulas:
$$
\begin{split}
\phi(m) \equiv & m \geq k + 2 \\ &\land (\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)(\forall z)[x = b_{m,m} \land y = a_{m,m} \land z = 2^{-k+2} \to x - y < z]
\end{split}
$$
and
$$
\begin{split}
\phi(m) \equiv & m \geq k + 2 \\ & \land (\exists x)(\exists y)(\exists z)[y = b_{m,m} \land y = a_{m,m} \land z = 2^{-k+2} \land x - y < z]
\end{split}$$
Here

- $x = b_{m,m}$ is the formula that says the ordered pair $((m,m),x)$ is in $b$
- $y = a_{m,m}$ is a formula that says that the ordered pair $((m,m),y)$ is in $a$
- $z = 2^{-k+2}$ is a formula that says $z = 2^{-k+2}$. The most straightforward way to handle $z$ is to show that there exists a set $P = \{ (k, 2^{-k+2}) : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, and then use this set as a parameter in the comprehension scheme, so $z = 2^{-k+2}$ can be an abbreviation for $(k,z) \in P$.

Actually, the formulas above are still abbreviations, because $x$ and $y$ are supposed to be rational numbers. So, in the second phase of the expansion, we would replace the quantifier for $x$ with two natural number quantifiers, one for the numerator and one for the denominator, and similarly for $y$. Then the formula $x - y < z$ will be replaced with a more complicated formula using only natural number variables.  However, the formulas above indicate to me that it is possible to express the desired definition in a $\Delta^0_1$ manner, which is the goal of the proof, so I will leave the rest of the expansion to someone else.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I understand now.

Comment: @Carl Mummert Good day Carl. Would you give your thought on this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426806/countable-choice-and-term-extraction ?

Comment: @Valery Saharov: for that question, I am afraid that I would have too much to say, and at the same time I might not say enough.  I have read the question a few times, but I am still not quite sure what you're asking.  I have generally always agreed with Bishop that choice is not a really issue for someone who works in a constructive manner from the outset; realizability and the BHK interpretation agree with this viewpoint.  But of course there is no agreement among constructivists in general.

Comment: @Carl Mummert I'd really appreciate if you could share your thoughts on that subject. No need to write much if you don't want to spend time for that. I should have included my own answer as a part of the question. Basically, the question is whether we can convert proofs with AC into working programs and if yes then how (in principle) and what example may be found. BHK doesn't help me understand. We have spent quite a lot of time discussing it with other people and no clear answer was given. Would be nice if you could just elaborate on that "black box" concept that many constructivists use

Comment: @Carl I refined my question. Since you are an expert in computability theory, I really think it'S worth your attention